# Operation on overlapping elements on IEnumerable by LINQ

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

Let us consider an `IEnumerable` and the algorithm that takes pairs of overlapping indexes e.g. {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3} etc. end creates a new collection based on values of these indexes e.g. {collection[0], collection[1] => result[0]}, {collection[1], collection[2] => result[1]} and so on. Below is an example of straight implementation:

```
IEnumerable<string> collection = new string[100];
var array = collection.ToArray();
var results = array.Skip(1).Select((e, i) => e - array[i]);
```

How to achieve the goal in better manner?

Comment: Your code sample doesn't appear to relate to the question.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var array = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, array.Length - 1)
                        .Select(i => new[] { array[i - 1], array[i] });
```

Here is @TrustMe solution with arrays instead of tuples (just to show you sample, you should not accept my answer):

```
IEnumerable<string> collection = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var result = collection.Zip(collection.Skip(1), (x,y) => new [] { x, y });
```

But keep in mind, that collection will be enumerated **two times** if you do not use access by index (with array or list).

---

UPDATE Here is an extension method, which will work with collection and will **enumerate sequence only once**:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> GetOverlappingPairs<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        enumerator.MoveNext();

        var first = enumerator.Current;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var second = enumerator.Current;
            yield return new T[] { first, second };
            first = second;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = collection.GetOverlappingPairs();
```

Comment: Seems that the custom iterator is the best aproach. Once declarated can be used very easy in query for overlapping items. `Zip` allows only to creates pairs, so I can't use more complex scenario like {0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}. `Range` is suffiecient for `ICollection`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var result = Enumerable.Range(1, arrayCollection.Length - 1)
               .Select(i => new[] {arrayCollection[i - 1], arrayCollection[i]});
```

If `arrayCollection` is `IEnumerable`

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, arrayCollection.Count() - 1)
                 .Select(i => new[] {
                          arrayCollection.ElementAt(i - 1), 
                          arrayCollection.ElementAt(i) 
                        });
```

Comment: Do you have and idea how to omit arrayCollection and use collection?

Comment: @yBee: afraid that I don't totally understand what you mean, please could you clarify more?

Comment: I would like to take overlapping pairs directly from IEnumerable not from an Array. I've created the array (arrayCollection) in my example in order to achieve the goal, but I wont it. I need pairs of values from collection that come from overlapping indexes.

Comment: Without assumption that collection is an array, the solution will be comparable with that where .ToArray() is used in advance? Is there any manner to store the current value over iteration in order to use it later in the query?

Comment: @yBee: Well, IEnumerable is representation, int[] is also IEnumerable, if you just query data, not change anything, IEnumerable is enough for you

Answer (score 2):

And here's another one:

```
var ints = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
var paired = ints.Zip(ints.Skip(1), Tuple.Create);
```

That way you'll get the pairs {0,1}, {1,2} ...

I assume that's what you're asking for, because your code sample is a tad different than what you described... :)

Comment: I hate tuples, but Zip is clever

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I have to admit, tuples are a bit clunky in C# (and Scala for that matter too), but it's always a pair... ;)

Comment: A pair with awful non-descriptive names :)

Comment: I need values, not indexes. But values of overlapping indexes. I need t[1] - t[0], then t[2] - t[1] and so on. I need pairs {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, ...

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Solution of Cuong Le meets the requirements and is better than that in my example.